# Hide a canvas ctx.rect() after 1 second - Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have a canvas which is filled with the webcam stream.
On top of that, I want to have rectangles (just the borders of a rectangle) appear for 1 second at random areas. So every second a rectangle will pop up, and the next it will be somewhere else.
Currently, rectangles are appearing every second but the last doesn't disappear. Therefore, on the 2nd second there are 2 rectangle, 3rd second 3 rectangles, etc...
I need to find a way to either have the rectangle appear for 1 second, have it removed after 1 second, or have it moved after 1 second: results are the same for me.

```
let sx; // x axis
let sy; // y axis
let i = setInterval( axisChanger, 1000 ); // pops up every second

function axisChanger() {
  sx = getRandomInt(0, 535); // gets a random num
  sy = getRandomInt(0, 445); // gets a random num
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  randomRect();
}

function randomRect() {
  ctx.rect(sx, sy, 50, 30); // these 4 lines make a hollow rectangle: border only.
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

If I use clearRect(), then the inside of the rectangle will also be gone... and so part of the webcam stream with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to draw a single rectangle, replace `rect()` and `stroke()` with `strokeRect()`:

```
function randomRect() {
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.strokeRect(sx, sy, 50, 50);
}
```

The reason for the current behavior is that `rect()` adds to the main *path* and accumulates all `rect()` calls. Because of that the path must be cleared using `beginPath()`.

But since you are only using a single rectangle you can simply use `strokeRect()` which does not add anything to the path but renders directly.

The alternative however, would be:

```
function randomRect() {
  ctx.beginPath();          // clear path and sub-paths
  ctx.rect(sx, sy, 50, 30); // these 4 lines make a hollow rectangle: border only.
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```